# Prevent form autocomplete from changing background color of input fields

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

I am creating a form with MaterialUI and React. When I populate the form manually I get the expected styling:
[image]

However if I use Chrome's autocomplete, the styling is changed as so:
[image]

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I don't want to lose the autocomplete functionality.

Comment: how about `autoComplete = 'off' ` on your input fields ....

Comment: I wouldn't want to lose the autocomplete functionality.

Comment: looks like z-index not working in this case .. put some sample working code to get help

Comment: check [this code pen examples if it helps](https://codepen.io/meodai/pen/rNedxBa)